# How to compare a lines of a text file with a line of different text file and append the first one if they are not same

Tags: shell, unix, solaris-10

I want to compare particular line of two  text file and update one of the file if they are not same.

Comment: "Append"? Or "update"? What do the files look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Please see this for information on how to better ask a question http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to compare the root device details(specifically not the whole file ) of one vfstab file with other and update the later if the details are not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updating* a line in a text file is technically not possible (unless the replacing line is of exactly the same length). You have to create a new file, which you can, in the end, move to the old one.

From your tags, I assume that you are looking for a shell solution, which is maybe not a good idea. It's probably more convenient to do it in, for instance, Perl or Ruby or Python.

One possibility is to use the commands `head` and `tail`, which allow you to dissect a file into parts. You can split your file into three parts: The part before the line in question, the line itself, and the lines which come after.

Another possibility is to use a loop and the `read` command of the shell to process a file line by line, like this:

```
while read line           
do           
  ... # Decide here, whether to write $line or the replacement line          
done <your_file
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response !! How to replace the line if they are of same length

Comment: If you use zsh as a shell, have a look at the commands `sysopen`,`sysread` `sysseek` and `syswrite` in the *zshall* man-page. However, in this case a **real** programming language would be easier to use.